# Delete the first line using Tie::File without leave a newline at the end of the file

Tags: perl, file, newline, blank-line

I use the following code to delete the first line of a file:

```
use Tie::File;
tie @task_queue, 'Tie::File', $queue_path or die $!;
shift @task_queue;
$#task_queue -= 1;
untie @task_queue;
```

The file content is like:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

But when I use the code, it will delete the line1 but leave a newline at the end of the file like this:

```
line2
line3
# <- here is a blank line
```

Since I use this file as a queue, if I add some new line after, it will become:

```
line2
line3
# <- here is a blank line
line4
```

So is there any way to avoid leaving a blank line when using Tie::File to delete the first line?

Comment: Are you checking for empties, or for the size of the queue?  does your last example equal a queue of size 3 or 4?  Can you just check your shifted value for /^\s*$/ and start a new iteration if it is?

Comment: Why are you doing `$#task_queue -= 1;`? If you're only trying to remove the first line, `shift @task_queue` should be all that is required.

Comment: @chrsblck Thanks for your advice, that's a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that help with this. I found a solution, it's not beautiful code but works.
I also found that the blank line is still generated even if I do only **tie** and **untie**(no action between them). It may be some design issue of the module.

```
use Tie::File;
tie @task_queue, 'Tie::File', $queue_task_path or die $!;
shift @task_queue;
untie @task_queue;
print("Removing the blank line.\n");
my $queue_task_file_size = -s $task_queue;
truncate($task_queue, $queue_task_file_size - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good solution, but it removes blank lines at the end of the file.

```
while ($task_queue[-1] eq '') {
    pop @task_queue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it still leave a blank line in the end of file.